# If sum of divisors is a $\mathbb{L}$ digit number, Then $\mathbb{L}$ is

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> The sum of divisors $2^23^35^37^5$ of the form $4n+1,n\in \mathbb{N}$ is a $\mathbb{L}$ digit number, Then $\mathbb{L}$ is

$\bf{Attempt}:$ Let $N = 2^23^35^37^5$,

Then $3^0 = 4n+1$ form

$3^1 = 4n+3$

$3^2 = 4n+1$

$3^3 = 4n+3$ and $5^0,5^1,5^2,5^3 = 4n+1$ and

$7^0 = 4n+1$ form

$7^1 = 4n+3$

$7^2 = 4n+1$

$7^3 = 4n+3$

$7^4 = 4n+1$

$7^5 = 4n+3$

So for $N$ is in the form of $4n+1$

We select $\{3^0,3^2\}$ and any power of $5$ and $\{7^0,7^2,7^4\}$

or We select $\{3^1,3^3\}$ and any power of $5$ and $\{7^1,7^3,7^5\}$

So number of ways $(2\times 4 \times 3)+(2\times 4 \times 3)-1 = 47$

could some help me how to go further, Thanks

Comment: your statment is an incomplete sentance, we don't know what you're asking

Comment: Where do you want to go further? It looks like you have your desired number, what else is there to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The divisors of $2^2 3^3 5^3 7^5$ of the form $4k+1$ are the numbers $3^a 7^b 5^c $ where $a\in[0,3],\,b\in[0,5],\,c\in[0,3]$ and $a+b$ is even. The wanted sum of divisors is so $(1+5+5^2+5^3)$ times $W$, where $W$ given by the sum of divisors of the form $4k+1$ of $3^3 7^5$.
 By considering
$$ f(x) = (1+3x+3^2 x^2+3^3 x^3)(1+7x+7^2 x^2+7^3 x^3+7^4 x^4+7^5 x^5) $$
we have $W=\frac{f(1)+f(-1)}{2}$, so the answer is given by
$$ 156\cdot \frac{784320+294120}{2} = \color{red}{84118320} $$
with $8$ digits.